# Stupid behavior of multi dimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

The problem is simple. I made a 3X3 tictactoe game with 3X3 arrays. But the problem is:

`array[0][3] = array[1][0]`

Which is strange because first of all, the array I made didn't have a fourth column. So `array[0][3]` doesn't even exist! And to make matters complicated, it takes the value of `[1][0]`

I'm having problems when I input co ordinates of my move as: 0 2

```
void displayBoard(int tictac[3][3])
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cout << tictac[i][j] << " ";
        } cout << "\n" ;
    } cout << "\n";
}



int Horizontal(int x, int y, int tictac[3][3])
{

    if(tictac[x][y+1]==0)
    {
        tictac[x][y+1]=2;
        return 1;
    }

    if(tictac[x][y-1]==0)
    {
        tictac[x][y-1]=2;
        return 1;
    }

    if(tictac[x][y-2]==0)
    {
        tictac[x][y-2]=2;
        return 1;
    }
    if(tictac[x][y+2]==0)
    {
        tictac[x][y+2]=2;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int Vertical(int x, int y, int tictac[3][3])
{

    if(tictac[x+1][y]==0)
    {
        tictac[x+1][y]=2;
        return 1;
    }
    if(tictac[x-1][y]==0)
    {
        tictac[x-1][y]=2;
        return 1;
    }
    if(tictac[x-2][y]==0)
    {
        tictac[x-2][y]=2;
        return 1;
    }
    if(tictac[x+2][y]==0)
    {
        tictac[x+2][y]=2;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void AI(int X,int Y,int tictac[3][3])
{
    int done = 0;
    cout << "\n-------------------------\nComputer plays: \n";

    done = Horizontal(X,Y,tictac);
    if(done == 0)
    {
    done = Vertical(X,Y,tictac);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int tictac[3][3] = {{0,0,0},{0,0,0}, {0,0,0} };
    int X, Y;
    for(int r=1; r<100; r++)
    {
    cout << "\n-------------------------\nPlayer play a move: \n";
    cin >> X;
    cin >> Y;

    if(tictac[X][Y]==0)
    {
    tictac[X][Y] = 1;
    displayBoard(tictac);
    AI(X,Y,tictac);
    displayBoard(tictac);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Space occupied. Try different cell." << endl;
    }


    }





}
```

Comment: Validate your _stupid_ input data. If it's out of _stupid_ range report a _stupid_ error and try again. ;)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Well !

Comment: The behavior your observing is the result of the way that C++ handles multi-dimensional static arrays. It just gives you a chunk of memory, and does pointer arithmetic based on the two indices you gave it. It just goes to the (rowlength*i + j)th location in the memory. Thus, you can give it invalid indices that still add up to a location in the correct chunk of memory, and C++ has no way to catch it. This is way you should build in range validation.

In terms of the problems you're having when you go to 0 2, you'll need to be more specific as to what specifically is happening.

Comment: where did you notice that array[0][3] = array[1][0] ?

Comment: I agree. Thanks for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add bounds checking. For instance when the user inputs the move coordinates you need to ensure they are within the range of 0 to 2. The example below validates the input to ensure only numbers are entered, that both X and Y coordinates are entered on a single line and that the coordinates are within range. It uses [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to parse the coordinates instead of having to deal with checking and clearing the fail bits on `std::cin`

```
#include <string> // at top of your .cpp file
#include <sstream>

// in main()

// Get en entire input line so we can skip extra characters
// after the cell coordinates
string inputLine;
std::getline(cin, inputLine);

stringstream inputStream(inputLine);

if(!(inputStream >> X) || !(inputStream >> Y))
{
    cout << "Please enter the cell coordinates in the form of # #" << endl;
    continue;
}

bool invalidCoordinates = false;

if(X < 0 || X > 2)
{
    cout << "invalid X location" << endl;
    invalidCoordinates = true;
}
if(Y < 0 || Y > 2)
{
    cout << "invalid Y location" << endl;
    invalidCoordinates = true;
}

// check for invalid input
if(invalidCoordinates) continue;
```

You also need to do the same thing in your `Vertical` and `Horizontal` functions when checking if a valid move is possible.  For instance if `x` is 2 and `y` is 2 the following lines from `Vertical` will access data outside the bounds of the array.

```
if(tictac[x+1][y]==0)
{
    tictac[x+1][y]=2;
    return 1;
}
```

This is because you are actually accessing the forth element with `x+1`. This element technically doesn't exist but with a multi-dimensional array you end up accessing `tictac[0][y+1]` instead.

You can get around the bounds checking in `Vertical` and `Horizontal` by adding some padding around the edges and fill them with a value that indicates they are unusable. In your case increase the size by 3 in each direction.

```
int tictac[9][9] = {
    {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
    {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
    {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
    {3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3},
    {3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3},
    {3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3},
    {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
    {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
    {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
};
```

You will need to make adjustments to `X` and `Y` appropriately so they point to the correct location.

```
X += 3;  // Adjust for padding
Y += 3;  // Adjust for padding
if(tictac[X][Y]==0)
{
    tictac[X][Y] = 1;
    displayBoard(tictac);
    AI(X,Y,tictac);
    displayBoard(tictac);
}
```

You may need to make adjustments in other parts of your code but the above example should get your started.

There is also a problem in your `displayBoard` function. When it prints out the elements of the array `i` and `j` are reversed so the board appears rotated 90 degrees. Change the following line

```
cout << tictac[i][j] << " ";
```

to

```
cout << tictac[j][i] << " ";
```

Another problem is that you are using `\n` at the end of each line you output without using `std::flush` to ensure the line is sent to the console. You can either put `<< flush;` after those lines *or* remove the `\n` and put `<< endl;` at the end of the line.

```
cout << "\n-------------------------\nComputer plays: \n" << flush;
```

or

```
cout << "\n-------------------------\nComputer plays: " << endl;
```

---

The code below is a complete update of the original code included in your question. It incorporates the above suggestions and makes a couple of other changes. I've also added an endgame check to determine if there are any moves left.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

static const int BoardSize = 3;
static const int BoardPadding = BoardSize;
static const int ArraySize = BoardSize + (BoardPadding * 2);

void displayBoard(int tictac[ArraySize][ArraySize])
{
    for(int y = 0; y < BoardSize; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < BoardSize; x++)
        {
            cout << tictac[BoardPadding + x][BoardPadding + y] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl ;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int Horizontal(int x, int y, int tictac[ArraySize][ArraySize])
{
    if(tictac[x][y+1]==0)
    {
        tictac[x][y+1]=2;
        return 1;
    }

    if(tictac[x][y-1]==0)
    {
        tictac[x][y-1]=2;
        return 1;
    }

    if(tictac[x][y-2]==0)
    {
        tictac[x][y-2]=2;
        return 1;
    }
    if(tictac[x][y+2]==0)
    {
        tictac[x][y+2]=2;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


int Vertical(int x, int y, int tictac[ArraySize][ArraySize])
{
    if(tictac[x+1][y]==0)
    {
        tictac[x+1][y]=2;
        return 1;
    }
    if(tictac[x-1][y]==0)
    {
        tictac[x-1][y]=2;
        return 1;
    }
    if(tictac[x-2][y]==0)
    {
        tictac[x-2][y]=2;
        return 1;
    }
    if(tictac[x+2][y]==0)
    {
        tictac[x+2][y]=2;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


void AI(int X,int Y,int tictac[ArraySize][ArraySize])
{
    int done = 0;
    cout << "\n-------------------------\nComputer plays: " << endl;

    done = Horizontal(X,Y,tictac);
    if(done == 0)
    {
        done = Vertical(X,Y,tictac);
    }
}


// Check if all moves have been made
bool isEndGame(int tictac[ArraySize][ArraySize])
{
    int count = 0;

    for(int y = 0; y < BoardSize; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < BoardSize; x++)
        {
            count += tictac[BoardPadding + x][BoardPadding + y] ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    return count == (BoardSize * BoardSize);
}


int main()
{
    int tictac[ArraySize][ArraySize] = {
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3},
        {3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3},
        {3,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
    };
    int X, Y;

    while(isEndGame(tictac) == false)
    {
        cout << "\n-------------------------\nPlayer play a move: " << flush;

        // Get en entire input line so we can skip extra characters
        // after the cell coordinates
        string inputLine;
        std::getline(cin, inputLine);

        stringstream inputStream(inputLine);

        if(!(inputStream >> X) || !(inputStream >> Y))
        {
            cout << "Please enter the cell coordinates in the form of # #" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        bool invalidCoordinates = false;

        if(X < 0 || X >= BoardSize)
        {
            cout << "invalid X location" << endl;
            invalidCoordinates = true;
        }
        if(Y < 0 || Y >= BoardSize)
        {
            cout << "invalid Y location" << endl;
            invalidCoordinates = true;
        }

        // check for invalid input
        if(invalidCoordinates) continue;

        // adjust the coordinates and do our thing
        X += BoardPadding;
        Y += BoardPadding; 
        if(tictac[X][Y]==0)
        {
            tictac[X][Y] = 1;
            displayBoard(tictac);
            AI(X,Y,tictac);
            displayBoard(tictac);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Space occupied. Try different cell." << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "game finished...check for winner" << endl;
}
```

---

Note: It's a bad idea to use `using namespace std;`. It pulls everything from the `std` namespace into the current scope (in this case the global namespace) and can cause conflicts.  It's best to use fully qualified names such as `std::cout` instead to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

In case of this array

```
int array[3][3];
```

the following statement is valid

```
array[0][3] == array[1][0]
```

because:

- C/C++ does not perform any boundary checks.
- 3x3 array is stored as a 1D array. When you specify the 2D indices, the compiler transforms them to 1D index: `[j][i]` becomes `[j * width + i]`.
- Thus, `array[0][3]` points to `0 * 3 + 3` (third) cell in a memory, but `array[1][0]` points to `1 * 3 + 0` (also third!) cell of the memory, starting from the start of your 2D array.